# Need help in deciphering a Litvish term regarding Yichud Hashem

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah, ramchal

I have listening to shiurim of R'Kessin, regarding the Yichud of HKB"H (Ramchal).

He uses a couple of terms I need to transliterate so I can do further research.

Phonetically: Yichud "shli tusoy" ---"The only cause" 
Phonetically: Yichud "mitz yuso"  ---"The only one"

Thank you

Comment: The Ramcha"l was not a Litvak, rather he was from an ancient Italki (Italian) family, which also produced such luminaries as Shada"l

Comment: I cannot figure out the transliteration that you use. Try using the Hebrew lettering or the link to where those words are used.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Brian and thanks for this first question. Can I recommend you take the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a sense of how the site works? Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: Thank you for the answer, that is helpful.  Here is the shiur I was referencing.  He mentions 3 different attributes of yichud in the first 15 minutes of this shiur.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Y2sa6j1lis

Answer (score 8):

It looks like the first is שליטתו -  His control, and the second is מציאותו - His “Existence”.